# How to use 'in' in Python with length constraint

Tags: python

```
ss = ''
for word in ['this','his','is','s']: # Attach the words
    if word not in ss:                          # if they are not already present
       ss = ss + word + ' '                     # to ss(substring) AFTER ss.
```

It gives output as:

```
'this '
```

But I want to get:

```
'this his is s '
```

How to do it using 'in' keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in all the other answers the problem is that the later "words" are all sub-strings of the first, however I would say that the problem is that you are comparing chalk and cheese or in your case words with a string - if you compare words with words the problem goes away:

```
>>> ss = ''
>>> for word in ['this','his','is','s']: # Attach the words
...     if word not in ss.split():       # if they are not already present in the list of words so far
...        ss = ss + word + ' '          # to ss(substring) AFTER ss.
...
>>> ss
'this his is s '
```

Which is exactly what you were asking for.

Answer (score 9):

```
ss = []
for word in ['this', 'his', 'is', 's']:
    if word not in ss:
        ss.append(word)
ss = ' '.join(ss)
```

Comment: It does not use the `in` operator with a second string operand, which I think was the spirit of the question.  +0

Answer (score 6):

Use a set, the problem with your code is that all `['his','is','s']` are actually substrings of `'this'`, so the condition is always False. (`in` looks for a substring.)

```
>>> 'his' in 'this'
True
>>> 'is' in 'this'
True
>>> 's' in 'this'
True
```

### Solution 1:

```
>>> seen = set()     #keep a track of seen word here.
>>> words = ['this','his','is','s']
>>> output = []
>>> for word in words:
...     if word not in seen:
...         output.append(word)
...         seen.add(word)
...         
>>> print " ".join(output) #This is better than normal string concatenation
this his is s
```

A smaller version of the above code using a list comprehension:

```
>>> seen = set() 
>>> " ".join([x for x in words if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)])
'this his is s'
```

### Solution 2:

Another approach(just for learning purpose) would be to use regex with word boundaries:

```
>>> import re
>>> ss = ''
for word in words:
    #now this regex looks for exact word match, not just substring         
    if not re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), ss): 
        ss += word + ' '
...         
>>> ss
'this his is s '
```

Comment: It does not use the `in` operator with a second string operand, which I think was the spirit of the question. +0

Comment: @mario because the problem *isn't solved* using `in`. For completeness you could add "You can't using in, but...". This almost like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @DanielB But... what I am trying to say is that it **is** possible to solve the problem with a "str in str" use of `in`.  I even produced an answer doing so...

Comment: @Mario You can also hit a nail in with a shovel, but it's easier to use a hammer. Your solution (while functional) is overly complicated (both logically and computationally).

Comment: I don't dislike the other answers. On the contrary. But instead of producing a duplicate (or quasi-duplicate) of other answers, I prefered to take an alternative approach. I can't see how my solution is "overly complicated" when the basic structure is the same as most others, and just happens to provide a quick implementation of the concept of "set of strings" as you would in languages that do **not** natively incorporate it. I admit it is certainly unelegant, but that's slightly different. Anyways. If I am really interested I should post this doubt as a question properly.

Answer (score -1):

An extremely simple trick doing just 2 (OK, maybe 3) small changes to your code:

```
ss = ' '
for word in ['this','his','is','s']:
    if ' '+word+' ' not in ss:
        ss = ss + word + ' '
result= ss[1:]
```

This even works for limit case "word" == `''`, which can be identified in the result as two consecutive spaces (or only one at the beginning).

### Explanation

I will use `':'` instead of spaces for visual clarity.  Processing of first item `'this'` is trivial and the result `ss` == `':this:'`.  Next item `':his:'` will not be found, and `'his:'` appended for a result of `ss` == `':this:his:'`.  And so on.

Comment: Hope the additional explanation helps.

Comment: You've made the code *more* complicated by using a different kind of delimited list that has less functionality than Python's *actual* list type. You should aim to simplify code, not make it more complex.

Comment: It's just a minimalistic alternative. And I disagree: **for the person who asked the question** the code is **not** more complicated, as he/she was already in exactly that track. I do agree that the code is more fragile (what if in the future we try to add compound words), probably more inefficient for bigger datasets (search in long strings is much slower than alternatives), and it doesn't show all the power of the language and/or how it's regularly used.

Comment: Additionally, it gave you the opportunity of explaining to the world what good Python code is, and what is not.